# Add label to Google "Universal Maps URL" link

Tags: google-maps

Is there any parameter I can add to a request such as the one in this function to display a name for an opened location, instead of showing the coordinates?

```js
  url(loc, label) {
      const prefix = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=";
      url = prefix + `${loc.latitude},${loc.longitude}`;
      return url;
    }
```

For example this is possible in Apple Maps with the `label` in the function below:

```js
    url(loc, label) {
      const latLng = `${loc.latitude},${loc.longitude}`;
      return `maps:0,0?q=${latLng}(${label})`;
    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: Yes I looked there but couldn't find it, that's why I'm asking here. Not looking to search for a place just to provide a name/label for the place that's being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Maps URLs for [Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action) only support two parameters; `query` and the optional `query_place_id`. There is no label parameter at this time. You can use `query_place_id` to show a textual name though, and Google specifically recommends this when querying lat/lng coordinates.

See this example: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY

[Android intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#search_for_a_location) do support using a label parameter.

Hope this answers your question.