# Add custom label to a google maps URL with GPS point

Tags: google-maps, url, gps

There are numerous SO questions on how to build a URL with a custom GPS location in a google maps URL.
But I can't find something where I can add a custom label to my point.

E.g. I can show a marker by building a URL like this:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512

But it's just an unnamed point. Can I add a custom label? Like "MyHouse"?

I actually want to add multiple points each with it's own label.
Something like:
http://maps.google.com/maps/dir/24.197611,120.780512//24.297611,121.780512//24.117611,120.180512
and then call the 3 points: House1, House2 and House3

Answer (score 0):

Although you can pass map parameters thought the URL it appears as though changing the marker icon is not an option.
[Google Maps URL Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

You can change the marker icons with the [Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-marker).

[Android Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#search_for_a_location) support label parameters, but the Maps URL currently does not support them. Check out [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281897/add-label-to-google-universal-maps-url-link) post about it

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. The marker itself is not a concern for me. Just want to label it so that users opening up the page will know what all the circles are.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest filing a Feature Request in our [**Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com) will be a good idea.

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects. You can learn more [**here**](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Answer (score 0):

Bing map does allow add a pin with label with url parameter:

`https://www.bing.com/maps?cp=${mapCenterLat}~${mapCenterLon}&lvl=${zoomLevel}&sp=point.${pinLat}_${pinLon}_${name}_${description}_${linkUrl}_${photoUrl}`

The `name` and the following parameters are optional.

However, allow add label could be a dangerous decision,
frauds may add misleading label to the map or on the wrong position.

[Bing map docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-a-custom-map-url#collections-categories)